# How to generate RequestToken URL for Google API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-python-client

I'm writing Python 2.7 desktop application which needs to access Google Spreadsheets using OAuth 2.0. I'va found a library for Google Spreadsheets for python [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) which uses [this](https://github.com/google/oauth2client) python OAuth2.0 library. The flow for desktop applications described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#installed) tells me that I have to generate RequestToken URL first which user can use to get Authorization Code to the application.

I already have Client ID and Client Secret generated in Developer's Console. But I can't figure out what class/method I can use to generate RequestToken URL in python.

Should I somehow construct it myself or is there an API to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out from documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#step1_get_authorize_url)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import oauth2client

from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id='your_client_id',
                           client_secret='your_client_secret',
                           scope='https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
                           redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')

auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

print auth_uri
```

You'd need your own client_id and client_secret here though.